# Wi-Fi baby monitor with local and remote viewing

Tags: sleep

I am thinking about buying a wifi camera like DropCam - for remote monitoring. However, I am quite worried about having to do a complete round trip to the Clound and back just to watch the live feed when I am at home.

Are there any systems that would let me watch the live stream via wi-fi when I am connected to the same network as the camera, and also offer remote viewing (I don't care about lags as much there)?

Comment: Sorry, but questions about picking specific products ("shopping recommendations") are considered [off-topic](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: I would add that questions about _how_ to select a particular product are fine (and this particular question has at least some close relatives if you search for "baby monitor").  Similarly, questions similar to "Is this a good idea" would be fine, or "concerns with ...".  Just not questions asking for specific products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most any IP camera should do that; you just have to set up port forwarding, and assign an IP (if your modem (assuming DSL or Cable or Fiber connection into your home) uses a dynamic IP address, a free service using Dynamic DNS will be essential).  Any router will have a guide for setting up port forwarding, and most IP cameras will also allow you to set up security and ports so that you can see the camera's feed when you're outside your network.

<sub>We use Foscam IP cameras in the kids' rooms, and Dynamic DNS + port forwarding have allowed us to view the cameras when we aren't home.  The setup wasn't bad, and I usually only unlock the port when we know we will be away and the kids are home, to minimize security issues.</sub>